# Placing two pictures in exactly the same place with css and showing on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover

Im working on my button and trying add two images (arrows) on same position. On hover one should hide and second show.

My problem is that the images (arrows) are next to each other and they should overlap

Before hover:

[image: Before hover:]

After: hover:

[image]

My code:

```css
.shop-button {
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 20px 25px 21px 25px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out, border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;

      .arrow-image {
          opacity: 0;
        }

      &:hover {
        background-color: black;
        border-color: black;
        color: white;
        .arrow-image-hover {
          opacity: 0;
          transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
        .arrow-image {
          opacity: 1;
          transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
        }
      }
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      img {
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
    <a class="shop-button" [routerLink]="'/shop'">GO TO SHOPPING
        <img src="/assets/arrow_1.svg" class="arrow-image"  alt="arrow" />
        <img src="/assets/arrow_2.svg" class="arrow-image-hover"  alt="arrow" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

Im trying something with position absolute but its not working

Comment: This should be achievable with `position: absolute`. But it would be a lot easier if you used font icons or simply arrows like this one → in your HTML

Answer (score 3):

Would you consider using just css and [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/long-arrow-alt-right?style=solid)  If so you can do it very simply.  The library is free.

```css
body {
   font-family: "Avenir Next", sans-serif;
   background: #ccc;
   padding: 100px;
}
.shopping {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.shopping:hover {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    color: white;
    background: black;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in;

}

.shopping i {
    color: black;
    margin: 0 6px;
}

.shopping:hover i {
    margin: 0 6px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>

<body>

    <a href="" class="shopping">
        GO TO SHOPPING <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right"></i>
    </a>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If the cursor is not hovering on the button then you should add
`display: none;` to the white arrow and add `display: none;` to black arrow when the cursor is hovering.